# How to click a hyperlink using .click() in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts

I am trying to read an article but I a am bored of pressing the hyperlink "next page" and tried to run the code below.

(***what is the code for*** ***:*** Pressing enter will find the hyperlink of class "x-hidden-focus") and click it.

The code written below worked by clicking a button when pressing enterKey for another webpage, yet it didn't work with a hyperlink .I tried to run the code that is commented but neither codes fixed my problem.

The class of the hyperlink I want to press is ".x-hidden-focus"

This is the [link to the article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started).

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){
var which = (event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode);
if(which == '13'){
    //$(".x-hidden-focus")[0].click();
    $(".x-hidden-focus").click();
}
});
```

> **NOTE:** I am using this code as a userscript in tampermonkey (Hope this helps).

Comment: Can you clarify your question with the following

You have provided the JS but you havent provided the HTML
So what is happening on the HTML

Your jQuery is querying a class selector and thus could be an array of elements
This may or may not be the problem, but until you provide the HTML to go with it, I cant state for sure, is there a reason you didnt give the URLs an ID instead to make it specific

Comment: I tried that code also but it didn't work.I want to be more educated (does [0] selects the first element in array list of class ".x-hidden-focus")?

Comment: If memory serves me well, im pretty much sure CLICK is for forms ie buttons.
Check the post out provided by @Alex beneath as I believe setting the browser location to the URL (HREF) will equally work

Answer (score 2):

You could try to simply navigate to to the href described by the link you are trying to click:

```
document.location = $("a.x-hidden-focus").attr("href")
```

Which with your code would become :

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){
    var which = (event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode);
    if(which == '13'){
        document.location = $("a.x-hidden-focus").attr("href");
    }
});
```

Based on the article you have provided we can see that the html for the button you are trying to click is the following:

```
<a href="adding-a-controller" data-linktype="relative-path" class="x-hidden-focus">Next</a>
```

However if you do press next we can see that there is now 2 buttons :

```
<a href="getting-started" data-linktype="relative-path" class="x-hidden-focus">Previous</a>
<a href="adding-a-view" data-linktype="relative-path" class="x-hidden-focus">Next</a></p>
```

And now your code would be :

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){
    var which = (event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode);
    if(which == '13'){
        document.location = $("a.x-hidden-focus:contains('Next')").attr("href");
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

My assumptions that the class was already present on the element was wrong.

Since the class is only added after you hover the link you would need to find the link only based on the text:

```
$("a:contains('Next')");
```

You could however be more precise by using the container class:

```
$("div.step-by-step").find("a:contains('Next')").attr("href")
```

Comment: Vote up as that would seem to work, question is, is that mobile phone friendly, as I am sure mobile browsers dont like the javascript redirecting due to mobile data charges

Comment: @DataCure It triggers when the enter key is pressed, which I don't think is relevant to mobile.

Comment: You could improve the selector to only get the correct button, in this case it would be `$('.x-hidden-focus:contains("Next")')`, your code guides to a wrong page now

Comment: This code is just made for me .By the way this code took me to a link 404 Link ended in (/undefined) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/undefined

Comment: The "next" anchor doesn't have any class at the start, the described class is added after we hover.

Answer (score 1):

The button on the documentation page is dynamically created and the class doesn't exist on it unless you click/hover it. You will need to select the button by

```
$('a:contains("Next")')
```

then get the first one of the resulting three links and take its href

```
$('a:contains("Next")').eq(0).attr('href')
```

Now you can set the location

```
document.location = $('a:contains("Next")').eq(0).attr('href')
```

---

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){
    var which = (event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode);
    if(which == '13'){
        document.location = $('a:contains("Next")').eq(0).attr('href')
    }
});
```

Comment: That worked for me.Thanks.I think i can do the same for the previous link also?

Comment: Yes. Just take Previous instead of Next then

Comment: I did the same for the previous link it worked.Just after few days something goes wrong and no event.which is captured other than 13(enter Key).

Comment: I was wondering what key events can be recognized other than (enterKey)=13?

Comment: I used this [site](http://keycode.info/) to extract the keycodes of every button but none works other than the enterKey=13

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add listener for click event like this:

```
$(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
  $('.x-link').click(); 
}
 $('.x-link').on('click', function() {
    let url = $(this).attr('href')
    window.open(url)
  })
})
```

[Here is example](https://jsfiddle.net/e9cjbo61/)

Answer (score 0):

As @bambam said You have to select the Link first by:

```
   `$('a:contains("Next")')`
```

Then navigate to the href described by the link by:

```
    $('a:contains("Next")').eq(0).attr('href')
```

And you can do the same for the Previous link.Your Final code would be:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event){
var which = (event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode);
if(which == '13'){
    document.location = $('a:contains("Next")').eq(0).attr('href')
}
else if(which == '16'){
    document.location = $('a:contains("Previous")').eq(0).attr('href')
}
});
```

> When you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> *Keycode:13* you go to the next page.
>
> When you press <kbd>Shift</kbd> *Keycode: 16* you go to the previous page.

Comment: I think your code works best where `.keydown` has better performance in my case instead of `.keypress`.